# ethers.js - approve function returns "Error: cannot estimate gas"

Tags: solidity, remix, ethers.js, erc-20-approve

I tried to create an ERC-20 token on the Ropsten testnet and then tried to call the approve() function but it returns this error:

> Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual
> gas limit (error={"reason":"cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail
> or may require manual gas
> limit","code":"UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT","error":{"code":-32000,"message":"execution
> reverted"},"method":"estimateGas","transaction":{"from":"0x0aC46d0fAD2EB451858e63605C3930b47E15fD95","gasPrice":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x7fbe46d9"},"to":"0xE81370807A2197D1aDDB0abdBE78FaD98fBc8052","data":"0x23b872dd0000000000000000000000000ac46d0fad2eb451858e63605c3930b47e15fd95000000000000000000000000e84389ec084def478cd64bf9f101390b436bd364000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a","accessList":null}},
> tx={"data":"0x23b872dd0000000000000000000000000ac46d0fad2eb451858e63605c3930b47e15fd95000000000000000000000000e84389ec084def478cd64bf9f101390b436bd364000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a","to":{},"from":"0x0aC46d0fAD2EB451858e63605C3930b47E15fD95","gasPrice":{},"nonce":{},"gasLimit":{},"chainId":{}},
> code=UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT, version=abstract-signer/5.1.0)

This is what I did:

- I created a token with solidity and deployed it on the Ropsten testnet.
  https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x4ad3c2c76ac2e86247dd2e3df5f189f0e196de4a71809cfa41d7aee81900b053

Contract address: `0xe81370807a2197d1addb0abdbe78fad98fbc8052`

Then I did the following:

```
function getAB() {
    //copy-paste from solidity
    return [...];
}

provider = ...

...

const my_contract_address = '0xe81370807a2197d1addb0abdbe78fad98fbc8052';

const abi = getABI();

//the pvt. key of the account used to create the token
const pvt_key = '0x________________'; 

let wallet = new ethers.Wallet(pvt_key, provider);

const contract = new ethers.Contract(my_contract_address, abi, wallet);

const max_amount = 100000000;
contract
.approve(my_contract_address, max_amount)
.then(x => console.log(x), x => console.log(x));
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with the code, please?

EDIT: `approve` function:

```
function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool) {
    _approve(_msgSender(), spender, amount);
    return true;
}

function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint256 amount) private {
    require(owner != address(0), "ERC20: approve from the zero address");
    require(spender != address(0), "ERC20: approve to the zero address");

    _allowances[owner][spender] = amount;
    emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);
}
```

Comment: What does `approve` do? Can you share the contract code?

Comment: @Ismael added in the EDIT.

Comment: are you sure you deployed the contract correctly? the byte code look weird? can you can any other method?

Comment: @MajdTL why does it look weird? I deployed it correctly

Comment: Check the contract code / byte code .. the byte code does not look like erc20 byte code

Comment: @MajdTL [here](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x39c1fb474c07051fc4059be63a988e70d15f1d3a)'s another contract I just created and [here](https://pastebin.com/nE59pvZU)'s the source code. Still gives the same error.

Comment: Can you call any other method ? Like name , balanceOf or  symbol? I’m not sure that you are deploying the correct contract :(

Comment: @MajdTL you're right. Not even `balanceOf` works. It gives the same error (`cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit`)

Comment: try to deploy it using remix, easier than a script